# strange behaviour in blazor wasm

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a SAVE button when clicked invoke some function, which saves user-info in the database. Only admin guys can press the save button.

There are normal users(other than admin) where I am disabling the save button so they cannot press it and it works fine.

I login as a normal user and right click inspect in the browser and then go the save button and remove the disabled field, the save button enables and when i click the save button I am actually able to save the data.

What is the use of disabling the button ? How to over come this. Is this the default behavior ? Anybody knowing how to play around with html data can actually override the behavior?

Comment: Why is that so strange to you? You button click event logic still has to do business logic checks to see if user is admin just like if you were working in a a say MVC web application. You would not just let your app be protected by front end validation...

Comment: Additionally to what @Marko said, you can also remove the `@onclick` event when the button is disabled. Also don't forget Blazor WASM is running on client, therefore, anything running on the client side is potentially unsecured. Lastly, disabling a button is UI/UX for the user, not a security for your logic.

Comment: In situations like these why even show the button at all if it will always be disabled? Use an `<AuthorizeView>` and only show the button to those roles that can click it. If you really want to show a button to users who won't ever be able to click it then you can use the `<Authorized>` and `<NotAuthorized>` tags to display two different versions of the button.

Comment: "Anybody knowing how to play around with html data can actually override the behavior?"  You're whole WASM application is an open book to anyone with the right tools.   As this is WASM, surely you check the authentication and authorization of the identity submitting a backend API call to save?  Surely it can't all hinge on disabling buttons in the UI.